# Is there any significance in the text above the door in Outlander?

Tags: outlander

***Outlander*** (Season 1 Episode 1) features a scene where Claire and Frank Randall arrive in Scotland and notice "sacrificial blood" in doorways.

Frank explains the blood and the Pagan origins, but I am wondering if there is any significance in the markings which seem to me to be

> J7 GL 4 BD77

above the door in this screenshot?  I would imagine there would be, or why else would they pause on this particular door?

[image: Outlander Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this question into an Outlander fan page on Facebook and an answer which was given was that the scene was filmed in Fife, where there is a tradition of "marriage lintels" recording the initials of the couple who lived there first and the date.

This one is more likely to be 17 GL (4?) BD 77 - that is, the home of GL and BD with the date 1777.  That "J" shape is not uncommon for "1".